# Detecting key strokes in a web form

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I've got a web form textbox with text mode set to multiple. Recently a feature stopped working and I can't figure out what happenned. When a user hit the [Return] key two consecutive times, the webform would trigger a submit button event via a client side javascript. Like this:

```
function postPage() {       
    var inputString = document.getElementById("Search1_AccordionPane2_content_txtSearchText").value;

    if (inputString.match(/(\r\n){2,}/)) {
        document.getElementById("Search1_AccordionPane2_content_txtSearchText").click();
    }
}
```

The code hasn't changed, our users use IE8 on W7 and I suspect that this stopped working since going W7 or IE8. Also the browser settings are restricted by the group policy that I don't control. Any ideas where to start debugging this?

Thank you,

Risho

Comment: and what is the event listener?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try making the `\r` optional with a following `?` so: `/(\r?\n){2,}/`, Just in case IE8 uses a single `\n` instead of `\r\n` as a line terminator

Comment: Unfortunately, I have access to neither IE8 or W7 to try out other things to suggest.  maybe try something like `alert(inputString.replace('\n', '[n]').replace('\r','[r]'));` to find out what you should be looking for in the string (assuming the match is the part that fails)

Comment: I just tested it in IE8 on WinXP (sorry, I guess I lied) and the match worked, can you post your event handler code?

Comment: The control resides on .ascx file and look like this: <asp:TextBox ID="txtSearchText" onKeyUp="postPage();" runat="server" Height="80px" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="240px" />. The javascript function: function postPage() {
        
        var inputString = document.getElementById("Search1_AccordionPane2_content_txtSearchText").value;
        
        if (inputString.match(/(\r\n){2,}/)) {
            document.getElementById("Search1_AccordionPane2_content_txtSearchText").click();
        }
    }

Comment: dumb question: Does asp automatically update the textbox ID from `txtSearchText` to `Search1_AccordionPane2_content_txtSearchText`? because otherwise your getElementById won't match

Comment: The Search1_AccordionPane2_content_txtSearchText was initially obtained from the rendered page "view source".

Comment: Hm... I think my next debugging step would be to put an alert inside the `post_page` function to make sure the event is firing, as well as one inside the `if()` statement to see if the match is working. If both of those work, try calling `.submit()` on your form instead of `.click()` on your submit button

Comment: Thanks for your help. Not sure why but the code changed, the .click() method was supposed to be on the button not on the textbox.